# Caption issue with Latex Figure numbers

Tags: captions

I'm working with Overleaf (Online Latex Editor) and I have an issue with captions when I add a new figure. It generates automatically the figure number but it's bad written.

This is my code when I add a new figure:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.29]{Git_Dashboard.PNG}
    \caption{Dashboard du projet Serious Game sur InnerSource}
\end{figure}
```

And this is the ouput:

> Figure
>   1.: Dashboard du projet Serious Game sur InnerSource

I have `Figure 1.:` and I would like to get `Figure 1:` or just `Figure 1`.

How I can solve this issue ?

This is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{interact}

\usepackage{epstopdf}% To incorporate .eps illustrations using PDFLaTeX, etc.
\usepackage{subfigure}% Support for small, `sub' figures and tables

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,merge]{natbib}% Citation support using natbib.sty
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{n}{,}{,}% Citation support using natbib.sty
\renewcommand\bibfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}% Bibliography support using natbib.sty
\renewcommand\citenumfont[1]{\textit{#1}}% Citation numbers in italic font using natbib.sty
\renewcommand\bibnumfmt[1]{(#1)}% Parentheses enclose ref. numbers in list using natbib.sty

\theoremstyle{plain}% Theorem-like structures
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.29]{Git_Dashboard.PNG}
    \caption{Dashboard du projet Serious Game sur InnerSource}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please post a minimal *compilable* code reproducing your problem, not just a snippet?

Comment: The answer may depend on your document class and the packages you load.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the "interact" documentclass. if this is compiled with the article class it works.

Comment: Is the `interact` document class available online somewhere?

Comment: Please make somehow available the `interact` class file you are using. Otherwise the MWE is not compilable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you perhaps using the `interact` template from 
[International Journal of Human–Computer Interaction](https://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?show=instructions&journalCode=hihc20)? It links to [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/taylor-and-francis-latex-template-for-authors-interact-layout-plus-apa-reference-style/jqhskrsqqzfz).

The template's preamble has

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

which stops the `caption` package from loading so that it doesn't override `interact`'s caption redefinition. But your code has

```
\usepackage{subfig}
```

so `caption` *has* indeed overriden things.

Therefore you can follow the journal sample code's example, and add the `caption=false` option to your `subfig` package line.

Comment: When I add `caption=false`, the caption works fine with good syntax but it's not centered. Do you know how I can centered this ? I tried to add `\centering` just before `\caption` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That's exactly how the journal's template has styled captions, i.e. the figure captions _are_ meant to be justified, not centered; so you shouldn't change it.